# How to combine POS tag feature with associated word vector for word get from Pretrained gensim word2vec ans use in embedding layer in keras

Tags: python-3.x, keras, gensim

I have already pretrained word2vec in gensim. In keras , I want to  use Word vector for word get from pretrained word2vec combined with that word's POS tag feature that i encode in one hot vector. In Keras, I  think use embedding matrix  So, I want to make embedding layer in Keras to achieve this so that It can be used in further layers(LSTM). Can you tell me in detail how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Just [merge](https://keras.io/layers/merge/) both the features. Take care of the shapes when merging, your word embedding layer would have 3 dimensions and POS you have is 2 dimension. You would have to convert POS to 3 dimension before merging.

```
from keras.layers import Input, Concatenate, Reshape
from keras.layers import Embedding

max_len = 100

word_in = Input(shape=(max_len,))
emb_word = Embedding(1000, 300, input_length=max_len)(word_in)
pos_ohe = Input(shape=(max_len,))
pos_in = Reshape((max_len, 1))(pos_ohe)
x = Concatenate()([emb_word, pos])
```